# Why getting Network - related error while connection to SQL server 2014 from Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to connect to my local SQL Server 2014 from Entity Framework and MVC API but I'm getting the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I've already googled for hours to solve this issue and have done the following things:

- Opened port 1433 in Firewall
- Checked SQL Server Configuration Manager to confirm all services are running well
- Allowed remote connection from the SQL Server Management Studio

I can create the Entity Model by generating model from the DB but when I'm running the API and the controller trying to connect with the (Model)LINQ then it is throwing the above error.

This is the piece of code throwing error:

```
         public int GetNextIdDocumenti()
      {
        int id = 0;
        using (var dbCtx = new USDevEntities())
        {
            dbCtx.Database.Connection.Open();//I'm getting error here
            var lastrecord = dbCtx.Documentis.OrderByDescending(x => x.IDDoc).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();  // At first I was getting error here then I've added the previous line
            if (lastrecord == null)
            {
                id = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                id = lastrecord.IDDoc + 1;
            }
            dbCtx.Database.Connection.Close();
            return id;
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me what else I can do now.

**Update**

```
  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entity.EntityModel.csdl|res://*/Entity.EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Entity.EntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\USDev.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

Currently I'm using attached DB to avoid this error but still getting the same error. So, my connection string is reflecting the above attached DB.

Comment: what is your connection string ?

Comment: @tschmit007 be carefull dont ask/post sensitive data here

Comment: Please check my Updated question with connection string for attached DB

Comment: Are you sure you have enable "Allow remote connections to this server" ?

Comment: yes I've enabled checked that option for this Server properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your server name correct `(LocalDB)`? how about the sql instance name `MSSQLLocalDB`? are you able to connect to database from Ssms using these configuration?

Comment: you are correct thanks a lot. It was not my server name. my client gave me this project to update so mistakenly I overlook this portion. My server name is localhost. Thanks again.